# Selected terms to be used in content type twice

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes, forms

I want to create a content type with two steps using [MultiStep](https://drupal.org/project/multistep)

First Step - Select names(Taxonomy) From Multiselect

Second Step  -Now I want to display the selected name on a Multiselect

How to achieve this?? I haven't tried anything because i have no idea on how to do it.

Comment: Have you tried doing with a hook_form_alter ?

Comment: @2pha i don't know what it is :(

Comment: You will need to make a module and put a hook_form_alter or hook_form_ID_alter to make changes to the form. Search the drupal api docs for these functions